What is the difference between Life and Being, in Neoplatonic thought, especially in Proclus?
In "Elements of Theology" Prop.105, Proclus claims that the immortal is perpetual, but not everything that is perpetual is immortal, this he argues, is because to be immortal means to always participate in Life, a priori excluding being not-living, and by Prop. 101 this participation of Life extends to a participation of Being. Yet something being perpetual, in the sense that it excludes being non-existent i.e always existing, doesn't necessarily have to participate in Life. All good and fine, however what is the difference between Life and Being? I know that the former is contingent on the latter, and that the latter has, as it includes more terms, more creative power and stands on an ontologically higher plane.

Life is the unparticipating principle of self-motion: "all that lives has self-movement because of the primal Life" (proposition 102). This contrasts on the one hand with Soul, which is a principle of self-motion, but also participates in the motion (proposition 20); and on the other hand with Being, which is the unparticipating principle of existence of any kind, regardless of whether or not it self-moves (proposition 101).
